# Can you make a nested column flexbox as small but as wide as possible

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the code snippet below, I have two flexbox containers: A primary one, wrapped row, and a second one, nested in the first one, that has a column direction.

I'd like to have the red, green & blue containers displayed like this:

```
--------------
red   | black
--------------
green | gray
--------------
blue  | 
--------------
```

instead of simply stacked like this:

```
--------
red
--------
green
--------
blue
--------
black
--------
gray
--------
```

Is this a possible behaviour? Thanks!

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox-element {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.flexbox-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.violet {
  background-color: violet;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}

.flexbox-element {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox" style="flex: 1; width: 500px">
  <div class="flexbox flexbox-element flexbox-column" style="flex: 1 1 100%">
    <div class="flexbox-element red"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-element green"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-element blue"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-element black"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-element gray"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox-element yellow"></div>
  <div class="flexbox-element orange"></div>
  <div class="flexbox-element violet"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html is fixed, right ? You have to use only css to reach your aimed solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `flex-direction: column` and the `flex: 1` to the first group, you should get what you want.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.violet {
  background-color: violet;
}

.flexbox-element {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.flexbox-group {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox" style="flex: 1; width: 500px">
  <div class="flexbox flexbox-element flexbox-group">
    <div class="flexbox-element red"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-element green"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-element blue"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-element black"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-element gray"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox-element yellow"></div>
  <div class="flexbox-element orange"></div>
  <div class="flexbox-element violet"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a stupid mistake in the html (I corrected it now). The order of the green and blue should be inverted and there might be more elements in the nested flexbox than those three.

Comment: This comes closer to it but it overflows horizontally: http://cssdeck.com/labs/sgjpfdcp
In the nested flexbox, I'd like to have 3 rows x 2 columns instead of 2 rows x 3 columns

Comment: I updated my answer, it looks like what you want to have for this first group

Comment: Thanks but it's still not correct as the elements in your proposal go from left to right and top to bottom: red, green (newline), blue, black (newline), gray. Is like to have them transposed : red, black (newline), green, gray (newline), blue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added a new class `flexbox-group`, have a look to my new answer

Comment: My original request should have been more explicit because, as I pointed out in a comment to the other answer, I'd rather not specify an explicit height and width for the nested flexbox. However it seems that it is not possible to achieve what I want without doing that so i'll mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for column flex, you need a fixed height to get this behavior

Answer (score 1):

1. CSS3 Multicolumns solution
2. CSS3 Grid layout solution

---

Due to the limitations of Flexbox when direction is column (you need to limit the height somehow or else it won't wrap in a second column), it's a simpler job for **CSS3 Multicolumns**:

```
.col-2 {
  columns: 2;
}
```

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox-element {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.col-2 {
  columns: 2;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
}

.col-2 > * {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 200px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.violet {
  background-color: violet;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}

.flexbox-element {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox" style="flex: 1; width: 500px">
  <div class="flexbox flexbox-element col-2" style="flex: 1 1 100%">
    <div class="red">A</div>
    <div class="green">B</div>
    <div class="blue">C</div>
    <div class="black">D</div>
    <div class="gray">E</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox-element yellow"></div>
  <div class="flexbox-element orange"></div>
  <div class="flexbox-element violet"></div>
</div>
```

---

You could also use **CSS3 Grid layout** but you'll need to position manually each grid item in IE10-11 and Edge 12-15 (current Edge 16 supports the same newer recommendation that other modern browsers)

Grid layout (compat Edge 16+ and other modern browsers. IE11 needs explicit positioning of both row and column of *each* grid item)

➡️ https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/GdBpJa?editors=0100

```
.col-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr)); /* 2 columns with strict equal width */
}

.col-2 > :nth-child(odd) {
  grid-column: 1; /* even items can now only occupy the 2nd column */
}
```